# Why am I getting the error "Bad number of arguments. Expected 2 or 3 arguments."?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running this query with window functions, and it's giving me the error "Bad number of arguments. Expected 2 or 3 arguments."

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT
   word,
   word_count,
   LAG(word) OVER (PARTITION BY corpus ORDER BY word_count DESC) lag,
FROM
   [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
WHERE
   corpus='othello' and length(word) > 10
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of LAG(word), use LAG(word, 1) to request the previous row. Same with LEAD().

```
SELECT
   word,
   word_count,
   LAG(word, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY corpus ORDER BY word_count DESC) lag,
FROM
   [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
WHERE
   corpus='othello' and length(word) > 10
LIMIT 5
```

(The BigQuery team is working in the meantime on a patch to support the unary form of these functions)